# Xamarin / iOS / Crash on Launch / mono_handle_exception_internal / mini-exceptions.c, line 2782

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Can anyone help me with the crash below? It only happens on Apple review and I can't reproduce it anywhere else. Of course, the app is rejected with "App crashes on launch".

We have been testing with approx 100 beta testers and have not found this issue. The Apple reviewer said he used an ipad (which is not included in the plist) but I don't know if that makes much difference.

```
Incident Identifier: a1e3bd73-85e1-4d6f-824b-eefb08825975
CrashReporter Key:   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:         Paroli.iOS [1930]
Path:            /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5689867F-D5A0-47C9-8F3B-E5392338B329/Paroli.iOS.app/Paroli.iOS
Identifier:      paroli
Version:         1.0 (1.0.24)
Code Type:       ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2020-10-12T15:26:01.776Z
Launch Time:     2020-10-12T12:19:17.688Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 14.0.1 (18A393)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 at 
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)', reason: 'abort() called'

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b9c0995c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d46679e8 pthread_kill + 208
2   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x0000000198670934 abort + 96
3   Paroli.iOS                           0x00000001030ef648 xamarin_unhandled_exception_handler.cold.1 + 32
4   Paroli.iOS                           0x00000001030e429c xamarin_unhandled_exception_handler (runtime.m:0)
5   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000102fa9c9c mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook (exception.c:1265)
6   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000102f3eafc mono_handle_exception_internal (mini-exceptions.c:2782)
7   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000102f3f4f0 mono_resume_unwind (mini-exceptions.c:3530)
8   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000102f3341c mono_arm_resume_unwind (exceptions-arm64.c:420)
9   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000100f2ed88 llvm_resume_unwind_trampoline + 164
10  Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000101e560b8 Xamarin_iOS_UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string (UIApplication.cs:0)
11  Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000102f506fc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini-runtime.c:3164)
12  Paroli.iOS                           0x000000010300bdb0 mono_runtime_invoke_checked (object.c:3052)
13  Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000103012008 mono_runtime_exec_main_checked (object.c:0)
14  Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000102f2ecb4 mono_jit_exec (driver.c:1383)
15  Paroli.iOS                           0x00000001030ebca0 xamarin_main (monotouch-main.m:485)
16  Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000100e2f0bc main (main.m:222)
17  libdyld.dylib                        0x000000018f67e598 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d466b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b9c0972c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d4660330 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 1176
2   Paroli.iOS                           0x00000001030af16c thread_func (mono-os-mutex.h:219)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d4666b70 _pthread_start + 284
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d466b880 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b9be6900 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000102fad020 finalizer_thread (mono-os-semaphore.h:84)
2   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000103059d8c start_wrapper_internal (threads.c:1232)
3   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000103059c10 start_wrapper (threads.c:1307)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d4666b70 _pthread_start + 284
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d466b880 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d466b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d466b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b9be68c4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b9be5cc8 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018f9a574c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018f99fbd0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1172
4   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018f99f200 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 568
5   Foundation                           0x0000000190ba9278 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 224
6   Foundation                           0x0000000190ba9158 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 84
7   UIKitCore                            0x00000001923109fc -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 500
8   Foundation                           0x0000000190d05c48 __NSThread__start__ + 844
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d4666b70 _pthread_start + 284
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d466b880 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d466b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d466b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d466b86c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b9c0972c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d4660330 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 1176
2   Paroli.iOS                           0x00000001030beaa4 mono_os_cond_timedwait (mono-os-mutex.c:75)
3   Paroli.iOS                           0x00000001030c7784 mono_thread_info_sleep (mono-coop-mutex.h:103)
4   Paroli.iOS                           0x000000010304df7c monitor_thread (threadpool-worker-default.c:728)
5   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000103059d8c start_wrapper_internal (threads.c:1232)
6   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000103059c10 start_wrapper (threads.c:1307)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d4666b70 _pthread_start + 284
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d466b880 thread_start + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b9be6918 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   Paroli.iOS                           0x000000010304e848 worker_thread (mono-os-semaphore.h:118)
2   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000103059d8c start_wrapper_internal (threads.c:1232)
3   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000103059c10 start_wrapper (threads.c:1307)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d4666b70 _pthread_start + 284
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d466b880 thread_start + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b9be6918 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   Paroli.iOS                           0x000000010304e848 worker_thread (mono-os-semaphore.h:118)
2   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000103059d8c start_wrapper_internal (threads.c:1232)
3   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000103059c10 start_wrapper (threads.c:1307)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d4666b70 _pthread_start + 284
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d466b880 thread_start + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b9c0972c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d4660330 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 1176
2   Paroli.iOS                           0x00000001030beacc mono_os_cond_timedwait (mono-os-mutex.h:219)
3   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000103065404 mono_w32handle_timedwait_signal_handle (mono-coop-mutex.h:103)
4   Paroli.iOS                           0x00000001030652dc mono_w32handle_wait_one (w32handle.c:0)
5   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000103065500 mono_w32handle_wait_multiple (w32handle.c:1002)
6   Paroli.iOS                           0x00000001030542e8 ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal (threads.c:2313)
7   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000102fce684 ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal_raw (icall-def.h:1100)
8   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000100e485e8 wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal_intptr__int_bool_int + 116
9   Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000101046d20 mscorlib_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOneNative_System_Runtime_InteropServices_SafeHandle_uint_bool_bool (WaitHandle.cs:90)
10  Paroli.iOS                           0x000000010103f474 mscorlib_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool (executioncontext.cs:910)
11  Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000102f506fc mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini-runtime.c:3164)
12  Paroli.iOS                           0x000000010300bdb0 mono_runtime_invoke_checked (object.c:3052)
13  Paroli.iOS                           0x000000010301169c mono_runtime_delegate_try_invoke (object.c:4434)
14  Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000103059e84 start_wrapper_internal (threads.c:1254)
15  Paroli.iOS                           0x0000000103059c10 start_wrapper (threads.c:1307)
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d4666b70 _pthread_start + 284
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d466b880 thread_start + 4
```

Comment: The stack trace you shared does not help much to find out the cause. You can use some third-part tools like appcenter to get the detailed crash information.

Comment: Thanks @JackHua-MSFT - I have App Centre installed but for some reason nothing is logged for these crashes that Apple have recorded. They have hinted that it's only on iPad.

Comment: Usually, iPad does not have much different with iPhone. Did you test on device with the same iOS version as the iPad?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I have manually uploaded the crash reports from Apple App review to App Center to symbolicate them

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes, both using 14.01

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT this is what Apple sent:-

Comment: Thank you for your reply. During our review, we found that your app still crashed upon launch. The issue does not occur on an iPhone. While we cannot provide technical assistance with the reported issues, we have put together the following resources.

To start, please review the App Testing Guide, which gives an overview of how to test your app to minimize the chances of issues occurring during review.

You may also want to review Designing for Real-World Networks, as all apps are reviewed on-device and in an environment that replicates real-world use of your app.

Comment: So did you test in a iPad?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I only had the simulator, but yes and it works fine. It displays small and in the middle, but no crashes.

Comment: Then you probably need to test in a real iPad.